# Using vim autocmd with edit problems

Tags: gvim, gvimrc

I'm currently attempting to create a basic screen layout for gvim that shows up every time it opens.  I'm also attempting to open buffers in a certain window.  Because of the GUI init timing I'm forced to open the buffers with autocmd.

So my _gvimrc looks like this:

```
winpos 4 2
set co = 200
set lines = 50
autocmd GUIEnter * vsplit
autocmd GUIEnter * wincmd b
autocmd GUIEnter * split
autocmd GUIEnter * edit /users/user/_gvimrc
```

The problem is when I do this the gvimrc loses it's highlighting. So I tried VimEnter but that doesn't work either.  Perhaps it's loading before the syntax files are sourced but I've no clue how to fix that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that syntax highlighting is executed as an autocommand and autocommands do not nest by default. The solution is to change that last autocommand to

```
autocmd GUIEnter * nested edit /users/user/_gvimrc
```

See

```
:help autocmd-nested
```

Comment: You're welcome. Maybe not so obvious, though. The reason I happened to know the answer was that I added a similar GUIEnter autocommand to my ~/.vimrc a few weeks ago and, like you, wondered for a while why my highlighting was messed up until I remembered the nested issue.